# Display the value of function in react native

Tags: function, react-native, couchdb

I have this function where i have to return/display the value of results, I'am using react native and couchDB as my database this code is inside of a flatlist.  I have tried this one but it is not working. please help me with this one.

```
 vacant (room) {
    
      localNoteDb
          .find({
              selector: {
                status: "vacant",
                room_type: room
              },
              fields: ['_id', 'room_type', 'room_no' ,'price','status','user', 'updated_at', 'hour_status', 'price_per'],
              use_index: nameIndex_status.status,
              sort: [{status: 'asc'}]
             
          })
          .then(result => {
               console.log('getListNoteFromDb', result)
             let getLenght = result.doc
    const results= Object.keys(result).length
    console.log('value of results: ', results)
    return(
      <Text> {Object.keys(result).length}</Text>
    );
          })
      
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
function Example() { 

  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);


  // Similar to componentDidMount
  useEffect(() => {
    vacant(...);
  });


  const vacant (room) {
    
      localNoteDb
          .....
          .....
          .then(result => {
               console.log('getListNoteFromDb', result)
               let getLenght = result.doc
               const results= Object.keys(result).length
               setCount(results); <-- This way -->
          });          
    }

  return (
     <Text> {count}</Text>
  );
}
```